# security configuration: access_denied_url not working

Tags: security, symfony, symfony-2.6

My application is separated in three parts:

- administration: `^/backend` protected by **ip**
- secured area: `^/member` protected by **login**
- public routes:  `^/`

Everything works fine except the `access_denied_url`. I tried specifying a route name as well as a plain path.

When I access `/backend` from an ip other than the configured one I get the following message:

> **Full authentication is required to access this resource.**
>   500 Internal Server Error - InsufficientAuthenticationException
>   1 linked Exception: AccessDeniedException »

In dev environment this exception isn't catched at all leading to a fatal error but shouldn't the `access_denied_url` option somehow redirect to the given url anyway?

This is my security.yml:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        backend:
            pattern: ^/backend
            anonymous: ~
            access_denied_url: /403

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                success_handler: my_auth_handler
                failure_handler: my_auth_handler
                use_referer: true
                check_path: login_check
            logout:
                path: /logout
                success_handler: my_auth_handler

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/backend,    roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [127.0.0.1] }
        - { path: ^/backend,    roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/userlounge, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/,           roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    providers:
        frontend:
            id: my_user_provider

    encoders:
        My\FrontEndBundle\User\MyUser:
            algorithm:        md5
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations:       1
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`access_denied_url` only works when the user's token is not anonymous and rememberme.

For more detail, see:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php#L120
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationTrustResolver.php#L65

Comment: That's interesting, do you know why that is? Even by looking at the code I can't figure out why this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to specify the option `access_denied_url` on the `security` node not on the specific firewall (`backend`) because I think it might be the other firewall throwing the AccessDenied Exception.

Source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

Alternatively you can create an AcccessDeniedListener, see this page for a tutorial: http://www.insanevisions.com/articles/view/symfony-2-access-denied-listener

Comment: Thank you, I already know about this solution but I don't want to go this way as long as there seems to be a more clean option.

Comment: I edited my answer with another solution (untested though). Hope it helps

Comment: In your access control you have ```^/backend```, have you tried ```/backend/.*``` instead?

Comment: Yes I have but the access control works fine. It is really just about how to use the `access_denied_url` option properly.